# Updating SLA on Queue change? How can I know if the queue has changed on a case?

Tags: apex

I want to update the SLA time set on the basis of the Queue Object. I have used a trigger to calculate SLA but do not know how to accommodate Queue in that... Suggestions are requested...

Queues are stored as a Group SObject, so

select Id from Group where Name = 'My Group' and Type = 'Queue'

But how can I retrieve that which case is assigned to which Queue?

```
for( Case caseObj : trigger.new)
    {
        // Access the "old" record by its ID in Trigger.oldMap
        Case oldCase = Trigger.oldMap.get(caseObj.Id);
         if (caseObj.OwnerId != oldCase.OwnerId) {
          //Logic for change of case owner
           System.debug('oldCaseOwner  :  ' + oldCase.OwnerId); 
           System.debug('NewCaseOwner  :  ' + caseObj.OwnerId); 

           // How can I relate the changed owner to the changed Queue. I want the Queue name here.     
         }
         else
           System.debug('No Change in Owner'); }
```

Also, One Agent can belong to different Queues at a time.

Comment: can you please elaborate on what the issue is?

Comment: When a case is logged... the case is assigned to a queue Q1 Automatically. Here, the SLA is 48 business hours. But before that if the Queue is changed from Q1 to N1, the SLA counter should restart. Now, the SLA will be 60 Business Hours from the time of change of the queue from Q1 to N1. There can be many other queue's like that and on every change the SLA should update.

Comment: Queues are stored as a Group SObject, so
select Id from Group where Name = 'My Group' and Type = 'Queue'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the Queue name from case object.. this can be clubbed with the given code

```
List<Group> groupName = [SELECT Name FROM Group WHERE Type = 'Queue' AND Id=: caseObj.OwnerId];          

 FOR(Group gr : groupName) 
{                      
 slaInHours =  SLAForQueue.get(gr.Name);       
 System.debug('Group Name :   ' + gr.Name);                   

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can go 1 of 2 ways here:

1. Create a trigger that compares the trigger.new and the trigger.old to see if the value for the Queue was changed on insert or update.  Here is a link to sfd99's blog showing a quick example of how you might accomplish this: http://www.sfdc99.com/2014/02/25/comparing-old-and-new-values-in-a-trigger/
2. You could probably accomplish the functionality you're looking for with a few workflow rules that evaluate ISCHANGED(OwnerId) on the case when it's edited. Then, you would need a field update to dynamically set the new SLA date based on the current owner. I would think this would be harder than going route #1 with a trigger.

Best of luck!

-Wes

Comment: I have updated my trigger to get the old and new value ... but I am still strucked  as I am not able to access Queue from the case object. I am not able to figure our how can I get the name of the updated queue from the case object.

Comment: for( Case caseObj : trigger.new)
        {
            // Access the "old" record by its ID in Trigger.oldMap
            Case oldCase = Trigger.oldMap.get(caseObj.Id);
             if (caseObj.OwnerId != oldCase.OwnerId) {
              //Logic for change of case owner
               System.debug('oldCaseOwner  :  ' + oldCase.OwnerId); 
               System.debug('NewCaseOwner  :  ' + caseObj.OwnerId); 
               
              //How can I relate the user to the changed Queue now...
             }
             else
               System.debug('No Change in Owner'); 

}